# Unable to create site collection, getting SQL error

Tags: 2013, site-collection

I tried to create site collection using central administration as well as powershell but getting error.

ULS log shows error message:

> "A large block of literal text was sent to sql (length 93794).  This
>   can result in blocking in sql and excessive memory use on the front
>   end.  Verify that no binary parameters are being passed as literals,
>   and consider breaking up batches into smaller components.  If this
>   request is for a SharePoint list or list item, you may be able to
>   resolve this by reducing the number of fields."

Tried to search on internet about this error, but did not got much information.

Comment: How much RAM you have in your servers? Also check performance monitor

Comment: Hi Amal, it is single server with application and sql are on same server. It has 20GB RAM. And performance monitor shows 14GB is in use.

Comment: Try stopping some services (search etc.) and retry creating site collection.. Also keep an eye on Performance monitor.

Comment: stop the all unwanted services  as well as reboot the Server.